# How to check App Engine's Quota?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there any way to check Google App Engine Quota?I need to check Quota using Java Api.  How can I do it?

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we retrieve quota stats on App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861020/how-can-we-retrieve-quota-stats-on-app-engine)

Comment: @Nick Johnson I don't think so, this question asked and answered 8 months ago

Comment: The questions are duplicates; the only debate is over which to merge into which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to the [com.google.appengine.api.quota](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/quota/package-summary.html) package.
It provides the QuotaService interface (with an implementation and factory) with several methods to check and monitor Google App Engine quotas.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.quota.QuotaService;
import com.google.appengine.api.quota.QuotaServiceFactory;

...
QuotaService qs = QuotaServiceFactory.getQuotaService();
long start = qs.getCpuTimeInMegaCycles();
doSomethingExpensive();
long end = qs.getCpuTimeInMegaCycles();
double cpuSeconds = qs.convertMegacyclesToCpuSeconds(end - start);
```

Comment: Is there any way to check remaining mail quotas?

Comment: @Cha no, afaik it's not possible.

Comment: Note that this allows you to see how much quota your current request has consumed, not how much quota your app has remaining.

Comment: @Nick - is there a way to check how much quota my app has remaining?  (via an API, not the admin page)

Comment: @Nick How can I check email quota I am current consumed?

Comment: @Chandanda Currently, you can't.