# get amount of used resources in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am thinking about implementing resource throttling in my application in google app engine.

My idea is checking whether I am running out of resources (for example, bandwidth) and disabling part of the website, using the final part of the available daily traffic to inform the user that the site is running in a "resources saving" mode.

I read the GAE documentation, but I just found that if I run out of traffic, it directly returns HTTP 403.

Is there a way to make my python application aware of the used resources and to try not to be so rude with my users?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we retrieve quota stats on App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861020/how-can-we-retrieve-quota-stats-on-app-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, there is no API that you can use for this.
Looking at the App Engine roadmap there is no such feature coming along any time soon.

The only thing i can recommend is you sign up for billing and recieve the 50$ free quota, it's here till 31 october. You can enable billing and disable it and keep the free 50$!

Hope this helped.

Comment: so I'll start thinking about implementing it in my application. It shouldn't be too difficult, although pretty annoying...