# Monitoring CPU Usage in App Engine with Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, quota

Is there a way to get the current cpu quota of app engine in python? (The value of CPU Time in the Dashboard Screen of Administrator Console)

Thx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we retrieve quota stats on App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861020/how-can-we-retrieve-quota-stats-on-app-engine)

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/quota.py

If that class is limited, then use [trial and error](http://wandsea.com/doc/appengine_doc/appengine/articles/quotas.html) or [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (slow).

It [appears](http://appengine.cofares.net/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Monitoring_CPU_Usage_in_a_Request) to do what you want, though:

```py
import logging
from google.appengine.api import quota

start = quota.get_request_cpu_usage()
do_something_expensive()
end = quota.get_request_cpu_usage()

logging.info("do_something_expensive() cost %d megacycles." % (end - start))
```

The new separate Python section for http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html appears to be unfinished.

Comment: Hi @Cees. Actually i want to get the current value of my CPU Time quota. (The one in the Dashboard screen of Administrator Console. Currently free accounts have max 6.50 CPU hours.) I tried 
usage = quota.get_request_api_cpu_usage() 
but it returned 0. Any more ideas?

Comment: Ask Google to expand their API or use urllib to scrape the admin console.